# Whitespace at the top of document when padding and margin at 0px

Tags: html, css

I have a div as the first element in my page. However, approximately 20 px of whitespace is separating it from the top of the page.

I have set both the padding and margin of the `<body>` and `<html>` tags to zero like so:

```
html, body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

However the whitespace continues to show:

[image: whitespace of approximately 20px]

Inspecting the document in the browser dev tools shows that:

- The body occupies only the orange area
- The `<html>` element occupies everything including the whitespace
- The whitespace is exactly 21.437px high

As a bit of a patch-up fix, I added this rule to the css to remove the whitespace:

```
html {
  margin-top: -21.437px;
}
```

But to me this seems like bad code. **Is there a more correct/elegant way to fix this, or is there something I am overlooking?**

Full code:

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body { /* Note removing this rule does not fix the problem */
  margin: auto;
}

.header-background {
  background-color: #FFC107;
  width: 100;
}

.content {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- The above 2 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header-background">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Header text</h1>
        <p>Supporting text</p>
        <a href="about.html" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `.content` margin:0px;  try the padding on `.content`. I've also had time where things contained inside will push it.

Comment: h1 default style comes with margin just use h1 { margin: 0; } i will see it it fixes the issue

Comment: @SamOrozco Didn't work, but the answers did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **.content h1** is using the default margin, so replace it with 0px:

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body { /* Note removing this rule does not fix the problem */
  margin: auto;
}

.header-background {
  background-color: #FFC107;
  width: 100;
}

.content {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.content h1 {
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- The above 2 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header-background">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Header text</h1>
        <p>Supporting text</p>
        <a href="about.html" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you know why the h1 margin get applied to the top of the page rather than to its parent element?

Comment: because browser..every browser have diffrent css style for div, p, h1, h2....h6...etc html tags..h1 parent is div. For div default css style is  display:block only.

Comment: sorry for my english. Hope you understand.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. And your english was good enough to understand, thanks

Comment: After inspect the any element. In css part there is user agent stylesheet part. See there those styles are default css style for that particular element.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `html, body` use `*` will solve the issue. It will remove all the default `margin` and `padding`  occupied.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body { /* Note removing this rule does not fix the problem */
  margin: auto;
}

.header-background {
  background-color: #FFC107;
  width: 100;
}

.content {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- The above 2 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header-background">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Header text</h1>
        <p>Supporting text</p>
        <a href="about.html" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And as long as other specific padding and margin values are set *after* this rule, they should work, right?

Comment: @angussidney Yes .All padding and margin define after will work.

Comment: Since I can only accept 1 answer, I accepted the other answer because it did not require the style to be applied to everything; however I did upvote a question and an answer of yours to give you the equivalent rep

Comment: @angussidney no worry man. But take in note for future. `*` will remove all the default margin and padding. If you use any other element which take margin or padding. Then you should write same for that also. Where `*` will remove for all.

Comment: I'd suggest that this is actually the better answer. Using `*` to reset browser nonsense is a very good idea. In fact, zeroing margins and padding is just the beginning. It's useful for setting your default font size, font weight, centering, `border-box`, etc.